# I am not able to read and send data into SQL Server through console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, console

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using HttpWebRequestResponse;

namespace JSONARECHESTRA
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main()
        { }

        public SqlConnection con =newSqlConnection(@"server=SERVE;database=DATABASE;uid=XX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlDataReader dr1;

        public void CONNECTION()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
        }

        public void executeNonQuery(string query)
        {
            CONNECTION();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public class user
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http:URL");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"Username\":\"DEV\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
                response = jObject["Rdata"][0].ToArray();
                JArray array = (JArray)jObject["Rdata"];

                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    int Alert_Type = Convert.ToInt32((string)array[i]["Alert_Type"]);
                    DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime((string)array[i]["Date_time"]);
                    string Location = Convert.ToString((string)array[i]["Location"]);
                    string Vehicle = Convert.ToString((string)array[i]["Vehicle"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(Vehicle);
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    Class1 cs = new Class1();
                    cs.CONNECTION();

                    string insert = "INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[TEST6] (datet) VALUES ('" + datetime + "');";
                    cs.executeNonQuery(insert);
                    // return Page_Load;
                }
            }
        }

        public string json { get; set; }

        public JToken[] response { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In this code I create a `SqlConnection` to the database and Http web service to fetch JSON data but failed to dump data into SQL Server and also my console window is not remain open to debug the program line by line

Comment: for debugging, did you set a break point?

Comment: yes i set break points but console window closing immediately without displaying my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Main()` method is empty. It is `console app` and you should use `Main()` not `Page_Load()` event. Place all code from `Page_Load()` inside `Main()` and delete `Page_Load()`.

Also you should make all of your fields, properties and method `static` because you don't create any instance.

**OR**

Change this line:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

by this:

```
public void Start() // or any other name
```

and `Main()` should be:

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 obj = new Class1();

    obj.Start();
}
```

**EDIT:**

You code should be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using HttpWebRequestResponse;

namespace JSONARECHESTRA
{
    class Class1
    {
        public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=SERVE;database=DATABASE;uid=XX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlDataReader dr1;

        public string json { get; set; }
        public JToken[] response { get; set; }


        static void Main()
        {
            Class1 obj = new Class1();
            obj.DoSomething();
        }

        public void CONNECTION()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
        }

        public void executeNonQuery(string query)
        {
            CONNECTION();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http:URL");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"Username\":\"DEV\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
                response = jObject["Rdata"][0].ToArray();
                JArray array = (JArray)jObject["Rdata"];

                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    int Alert_Type = Convert.ToInt32((string)array[i]["Alert_Type"]);
                    DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime((string)array[i]["Date_time"]);
                    string Location = Convert.ToString((string)array[i]["Location"]);
                    string Vehicle = Convert.ToString((string)array[i]["Vehicle"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(Vehicle);
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    this.CONNECTION();

                    string insert = "INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[TEST6] (datet) VALUES ('" + datetime + "');";
                    this.executeNonQuery(insert);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i can't get it i have changed Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) to public void Start() but problem remain same data is not going in sql

Comment: @R-T, did you change `Main` method?

Comment: yes and this is the error i m getting Program 'c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\JSONARECHESTRA\obj\Debug\JSONARECHESTRA.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: @R-T, are you sure your `Main` method is `static`?

Comment: static void Main()
        {
            Class1 obj = new Class1();

            obj.Start();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }i running this program but it throws exception the method or operation is not implemented

Comment: @R-T, because you do `throw new NotImplementedException();` Delete this line and add some code, i.e. `Console.WriteLine("It is Start() method");`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using HttpWebRequestResponse;

namespace JSONARECHESTRA
{
class Class1{


    static void Main()
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();

        obj.Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is Start() method");
    }




        public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=TNGSRV;database=astha;uid=sa;password=Admin@1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlDataReader dr1 ;
        public void CONNECTION()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
        }

        public void executeNonQuery(string query)
        {
            CONNECTION();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
       public class user

       {
           private static JToken[] response;
           static void start()

    {
        var httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://182.18.161.47:99/vts.svc/geo");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"Username\":\"wave\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
            response = jObject["Rdata"][0].ToArray();
            JArray array = (JArray)jObject["Rdata"];
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                int Alert_Type = Convert.ToInt32((string)array[i]["Alert_Type"]);
                DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime((string)array[i]["Date_time"]);
                string Location = Convert.ToString((string)array[i]["Location"]);
                string Vehicle = Convert.ToString((string)array[i]["Vehicle"]);
                Console.WriteLine(Vehicle);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Class1 cs = new Class1();
                cs.CONNECTION();
                string insert = "INSERT INTO [astha].[dbo].[TEST6] (datet) VALUES ('" + datetime + "');";
                cs.executeNonQuery(insert);
               //return Page_Load;
            }
        }
    }


    public string json { get; set; }





   }
}
```

i have done this but getting same problem still data is not going in sql as well as console window immediatly closing

Comment: You don't call the method with your code. Change your `Main`:
`static void Main() { user.start(); }`

Comment: @Roma could please paste the whole code with these changes